# Change color of specific word in html

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

On my site when comment text contains my company name, then I want this name to be highlighted. This comments are retrieved from my mysql database. So how can I change the color (highlight anyway) of my company name if it exists in a comment? I can't use `<span>` because comments are dynamic. So please help me.

**input**

```
<?php
  $paragraph=$row['textColumn'];//from database
  //now it is
  $paragraph='This is my companyName To be highlighted.This is  companyName To be highlighted.This is my companyName To be highlighted.This is companyName To be highlighted.';
 echo '<p>'.$paragraph.'</p>';
 ?>
```

**expected output**

[image: output]

Comment: What is the problem of using span in dynamic comments?

Comment: You have to use jquery to find the word, then wrap it in span tag with that styling

Comment: I do not know how to use it.because the word may exist or not in comment

Comment: Do you want to do it in JavaScript or PHP? You've tagged both. If you want JavaScript, your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525173/change-color-of-specific-text-within-html-tags-using-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use the search and replace method [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace):**

```
$paragraph = $row['textColumn'];//from database
//now it is
$paragraph = str_replace('companyName', '<span class="highlightClass">companyName</span>', $paragraph);
echo '<p>'.$paragraph.'</p>';
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use spans via a simply search and replace. You could do this in php:

```
$paragraph = str_replace('companyName', '<span class="red">companyName</span>', $paragraph;
```

Or in javascript (jquery):

```
$('div.comments').each(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace('companyName', '<span class="red">companyName</span>')); 
});
```

The above presumes comments are wrapped in `<div class="comments"></div>`. You would need to adjust to match your actual markup

Answer (score 0):

This can be done wih JQuery

```
var html = $('p').html();
$('p').html(html.replace(/world/gi, '<strong>$&</strong>'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $paragraph=$row['textColumn'];//from database
  //now it is
  $paragraph='company name';
 echo '<h1>'.$paragraph.'</h1>';
 ?>
```

**after it**

```
change h1 class style
```