# Change styling of a certain part in h1 tag when in Jinja template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jinja2

I have a question in a h1 tag which I am using JS to extract, like this...

```
var question = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
```

If a question (h1) contains the words 'tick all', I want only the 'tick all' (not any other part of the question) to be coloured green. So I started like this...

```
if ($("question:contains('tick all')").length) {

};
```

But I'm not sure how to code it further. Please help

In my HTML file, I have the following Jinja template code...

```
<h1>{{ question_text }}</h1>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change color of specific text within HTML tags using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26525173/change-color-of-specific-text-within-html-tags-using-javascript)

Comment: What about `<h1>Lorem, <b>ipsum tick </b> all dolor.</h1>`? Should this be couloured green as well? Like `<h1>Lorem, <b>ipsum <span class="green">tick</span> </b> <span class="green">all</span> dolor.</h1>`

Comment: You could do it directly in Jinja with `{{ question_text|replace('tick all', '<span class="green">tick all</span>') }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have only one h1 tag, then you can use like below

```
var ques = $('h1').text();
if(ques.indexOf('tick all') >= 0){
  ques = ques.replace("tick all","<span style='color:green'>tick all</span>");
  $('h1').html(ques);
}
```

For more than one h1 tag, you can .each function,

```
$('h1').each(function(){
var ques = $(this).text();
    if(ques.indexOf('tick all') >= 0){
      ques = ques.replace("tick all","<span style='color:green'>tick all</span>");
      $(this).html(ques);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Harry i have edited my answer for more than one h1 tag

Answer (score 0):

jquery version

```js
$('h1:contains("tick all")').each(function(){
 $(this).html($(this).text().replace('tick all', '<span style="color:green">tick all</span>'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>
 Ali tick all
</h1>
<h1>
 Ali tick none
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pick it out (below) OR if you want the entire H1 content wrapped:

```
var myString = 'tick all';
$("h1:contains('" + myString + "')").wrap(<span class='green-highlight'></span>");
```

**Pick out just the string:**

```js
$(function() {
  var myString = 'tick all';
  $("h1:contains('" + myString + "')").html(function(_, html) {
    return html.split(myString).join("<span class='green-highlight'>" + myString + "</span>");
  });
});
```

```css
.green-highlight {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


<h1>Hi, I am still me</h1>
<h1>Second one with tick all</h1>
<h1>Three wandering mice</h1>
```